# Log analysis gem not working in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Since memory leak was found in my rails app, I used request-log-analyzer to analyze the log. 
I added this in Germfile:

```
gem "request-log-analyzer"
```

and then run

```
$ bundle install
```

After that I tried to analyze the log file:

```
$ request-log-analyzer log/production.log
```

It worked in development environment. I deployed the app to production environment, and ran the same command in the terminal, it gave the error below:

```
request-log-analyzer: command not found
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try By using '-' instead of using underscore(_)

```
$ `request-log-analyzer log/production.log`
```